# My javascript code not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

My javascript code not working I dont get any errors but When I click submit button nothing happens I am fallowing a video tutorial I have watched twice but I cant find out what is wrong here

This is index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function gonder() {
         //   $('#sonuc').html("bekle");
            $ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"ajax.php",
                data:$('ferman').serialize(),
                success:function (msg) {
                    $('#sonuc').html(msg);

                }

            });
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form  id="ferman">

    <input type="text" name="ad" >
    <input type="text" name="soyad" >
    <input type="button" value="gonder" onclick="gonder();">
</form>
<div id="sonuc"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is ajax.php

```
<?php

$ad=$_POST["ad"];
$soyad=$_POST["soyad"];
echo "ad $ad soyadınız $soyad";
?>
```

Comment: Please, don't [delete](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39687136/) and repost the same question. Edit the original question instead.

Comment: You're probably wondering why people are disliking your question. You seem new to StackOverflow so I'll fill you in. You're supposed to ask questions that can assist other people.

Comment: Your code *will* error, because you have `$ajax` instead of `$.ajax`. So either you changed the code, or you're getting errors in the console and not telling us.

Comment: Well i missed that one @squint, good eye :)

Comment: ali ak: You had lots of people trying to help you before, and you didn't respond to them. Now you're not responding once again. If you don't care about your question, why do you ask?

Comment: @squint You are wrong but my english is very poor off course I care theese people thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the main problem is here:

Fix

```
$('ferman').serialize(),
```

to

```
$('#ferman').serialize(),
```

It's just simple mistake, really nothing to explain, considering that you used `#` id selector correctly on `#sonuc`.

```
function gonder() {
//   $('#sonuc').html("bekle");
     $.ajax({
         type:"post",
         url:"ajax.php",
         data:$('#ferman').serialize(),
         success:function (msg) {
             $('#sonuc').html(msg);
         }
    });
}
```

Update: As squint mentioned in the comments, and I missed it, there is a missing `.` in `ajax` call, should be `$.ajax`.
Thanks to squint to point that out anyway.

**Note:** There is no need to change input type from `button` to `submit` while we are making an ajax call.

Cheers :)

Comment: I don't use PHP. Would the lack of data cause the PHP response to fail? Can you give some information on what exactly is causing the failure? `Fix...to...Cheers` isn't enough of an explanation.

Comment: *"...really nothing to explain"* Of course there is. You're not explaining what specifically is causing the response to fail. That error in the code is certainly not going to cause the request to not be sent.

Comment: ...and the `type="button"` on the input will prevent the form from being submitted already. Don't need to `return false;`

Comment: Well it just looks like he is using selectors correctly, just missed that one `#` there. I could of course explain it as he is trying to refer to HTML element, instead of ID, but i think that he already know that. Btw I'll update my answer with `ajax` missing dot, as you mentioned, and `button` type. My fault to not point that out, thanks anyway.

Comment: I missed that missing `.` too at first. What I don't understand from either answer is why this causes a failure. As it is, the `.serialize()` method will return an empty string, and this isn't a problem on the client. So the failure must be somewhere in the PHP, if this is truly the issue, but there's no indication of why that PHP code actually fails.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put `#` before an id selector.  [More details](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

`<form  id="ferman">`

You are using this id `ferman` to serialize the form. According to id selector rules you should use -

`data:$('#ferman').serialize()`

Also you forgot to put a `.` before ajax.

**Correct code:**

```
function gonder() {
  $.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"ajax.php",
    data:$('#ferman').serialize(),
    success:function (msg) {
      $('#sonuc').html(msg);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Why does that cause the PHP response to fail? Does PHP error when you ask for POST data that doesn't exist?

Comment: Because if the form isn't serialize able or failed to serialize, php won't get the data from the form.

Comment: Yes, there's no data to be retrieved. What I'm asking is how PHP handles this. Does it error? If so, is it here: `$ad=$_POST["ad"];`, or is it here: `echo "ad $ad soyadınız $soyad";`, and what is the actual reason behind the error?

Comment: If there is no error on the PHP code, then why isn't it sending a response? The missing `#` isn't going to cause the JavaScript to fail.

Comment: It's depending error_reporting flag.  You will get notice like `Undefined index: ad` or `Undefined index: soyad` . Usually on production server error_reporting should be turned off. But on development server, you should fix these kind error.

Comment: So you're saying that the `$ad=$_POST["ad"];` causes the PHP to halt immediately if there's no `"ad"` in the `$_POST` data?